# Token Validation and Expireation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying the set up a user registration system that creates a token that expires after 48 hours (2 days). I attempted to program this but to no avail. When I test the code I get this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Error
>   Message: Class 'TimeDate' not found
>   Filename: models/User_model.php
>   Line Number: 58

Below is the code

```
    public function isTokenValid($token)
{
    $q = $this->db->get_where('tokens', array('token' => $token), 1);        
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        $row = $q->row();             

        $created = $row->created;
        $createdTS = strtotime($created);
        $expiredate = new TimeDate('Y-m-d'); 
        //$todayTS = strtotime($today);
        $expiredate->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));
        if($createdTS != $expiredate){
            return false;
        }

        $user_info = $this->getUserInfo($row->user_id);
        return $user_info;

    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: `new TimeDate` you sure you didn't mean `new DateTime` http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: I changed that and got this
Type: Exception

Message: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Y-m-d) at position 1 (-): Unexpected character

Filename: User_model.php

Line Number: 58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also use `strtotime()`

Assuming:

```
// the timestamp the token was created
$created = $row->created;
```

Since the token will expire after 48 hours, we need to add 48 hours to date variable `$created`

```
$expireDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($created . " + 48 hours"));
```

If you only want the date part and not the time, you can omit the `H:i:s`

You can now compare the `$expireDate` to today's timestamp.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
if (strtotime($today) > strtotime($expire)) {
    echo "expired";
} else {
    echo "not yet";
}
```